# CSS match only particular tags within ID

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me how to make this work.  In the following code I  need the h1/h2/h3/.tiny that are inside the #awesome_body ID to be red.  Any h1/h2/h3/.tiny not inside #awesome_body should use the browser's default color:

```
<body>
    <div id="awesome_body">
        <div id="show_body">
            <span>SHOWING YOUR...</span>
            <h1> AWESOME BODY!</h1>
            <h2> AWESOME BODY!</h2>
            <h3> AWESOME BODY!</h3>
            <span class="tiny"> AWESOME BODY!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="cool_body">
        <div id="show_body">
            <span>SHOWING YOUR...</span>
            <h1> COOL BODY!</h1>
            <h2> COOL BODY!</h2>
            <h3> COOL BODY!</h3>
            <span class="tiny"> COOL BODY!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

#awesome_body h1, h2, h3,.tiny {
    color: red;
}
.tiny{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/webteckie/q4FLd/3/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: It seems you think that `#awesome_body h1, h2, h3, .tiny` means `#awesome_body (h1, h2, h3,.tiny)`, but it means `(#awesome_body h1), (h2), (h3), (.tiny)`

Comment: You have duplicate ID's. ID's need to be unique.

Answer (score 3):

You would use the following:

[**Updated jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TRBbx/)

```
#awesome_body h1, #awesome_body h2, #awesome_body h3, #awesome_body .tiny {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prefix the container div's id for all selectors like so:

```
#awesome_body h1, #awesome_body h2, #awesome_body h3, #awesome_body .tiny {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want to select the `direct child` then:

```
#awesome_body > h1, #awesome_body > h2, #awesome_body > h3, #awesome_body > .tiny {
    color: red;
}
```

This will make sure that

```
<div id="awesome_body">
    <div>
       <h2>Text</h2> // is not red
    </div>
    <h2>text</h2> // is red
</div>
```